# Winston logger profiler time unit

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm using winston logger profiling.

my question is how can I change the time unit of the profiler.

My code:

```
this.logger.profile(`some ${jobId}`);
// do the job ....
this.logger.profile(`some ${jobId}`);
```

In the result I see:

```
{ ...,"message": "some 1", "durationMs":2500 ... }
```

My question is how (is) it possible to configure the time unit from ms to seconds/minuets etc...

So that I'll see

```
{ ...,"message": "some 1", "durationSeconds: 2.5" ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately no: winston doesn't provide an option of providing the duration in a unit other than ms, see:

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/profiler.js#L47